# Connecting to Pebble watch using Arduino

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, pebble-watch

I am curently looking to find out wheter it is possible to Bluetooth connect an arduino or similar micro controller to the pebble watch using the RN-42 [Sparkfun RN-42 adapter](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12576)
I currently am having difficulty connecting to the pebble, as the board just times out.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if it works with Arduino, but there is a modified version of libpebble: https://github.com/Hexxeh/libpebble

Comment: Is the Sparkfun adapter BLE compatible? The catalogue page isn't explicit about this. Your symptoms sound similar to what you'd see in Android if trying to pair a Pebble with a phone that doesn't support BLE. The Pebble can be seen in discovery mode but it can't be paired with.

Comment: You don't need BLE to connect to a Pebble. You do, however, need to be able to complete pairing (finicky) and open a Bluetooth SPP port (which that adapter appears to support).

Comment: cpf - what is the finicky pairing procedure, and what is Bluetooth SPP?

Answer (score 0):

The RN-42 can, using bluetooth.  The following will get you paired, and the watch MAY accept a ping:

```
SF,1      //factory reset

SP,9999   //takes care of the pairing code

SM,6      //pairing

SA,4 

SY,0000   //power

SW,0640  //sniff mode

R,1      //reset so settings are saved/active and pebble should ask to connect
```

To pass app messages you need to pass some information to the watch, see http://dexwatch.blogspot.com/2015/12/more-on-pebble.html for the full details.